# HTML Script run on BB 5.0 it works fine but not run in BB 7.0 OS?

Tags: html, blackberry

Can any one tell me that why delay happen when I run this script on BB 7.0 OS , on BB 5.0 it works fine

My code is

```
BrowserField myBrowserField;
myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
add(myBrowserField);
String content ="<html><head><style type='text/css'> p{color: blue;line-height:200%;}</style></head><body>"+
    "<p>Inspired by one of the most opulent among gems,Amber is our multi-tier Loyalty Programme</p>"+
    "<p align=justify>The Amber stone is associated with the fire element,Which is known to draw people,with itswarmth and radiance,while infusing a unique sense of loyalty into whatever it comes in contact with </p>"+
    "<p align=justify>This Programme is an example of our steadFast</p>"
    ;
myBrowserField.displayContent(content,"");//"http://localhost"
```

Comment: What kind of delay are you talking about? Where is the script that is being delayed? This looks like straight HTML to me.

Comment: It working fine in both os7 and os5. I think your RAM capacity is low.

Comment: Did u check this on simulator for os 7.0 Or model no 9860? @alishaik786,@jprofit

Comment: I worked in 9870(Version 6.0) and 9900(Version 7.0) with same code;

Comment: Can we see a some more code and profiler output. There shouldn't really be any delay on a 9900. Perhaps it is a firmware issue, have you tried upgrading the 9900?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add he "" seems you forgotten that one :)

```
BrowserField myBrowserField;
myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
add(myBrowserField);
String content ="<html><head><style type='text/css'> p{color: blue;line-height:200%;}</style></head><body>"+
    "<p>Inspired by one of the most opulent among gems,Amber is our multi-tier Loyalty Programme</p>"+
    "<p align=justify>The Amber stone is associated with the fire element,Which is known to draw people,with itswarmth and radiance,while infusing a unique sense of loyalty into whatever it comes in contact with </p>"+
    "<p align=justify>This Programme is an example of our steadFast</p>"+
    "</body></html>"
    ;
myBrowserField.displayContent(content,"");//"http://localhost"
```

I try on my 9790 with BB OS7 and nothing goes wrong and working out just fine.
For the delay beside the RAM, maybe you are installing to many apps...